# jQuery - Unable to Update View after Success Function without Refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm new in jQuery. I want to update the view without refreshing the Page. Data is logging in console but not loading in View without Refreshing.
$('#ajax').html( ajax); - Not showing me anything. I'm calling data AJAX.

Javascript

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#api_key').click(function() {

    var request = $.ajax({
      url: "/account/settings/api_token",
      method: "POST",
    });

    request.done(function(msg) {

      if (msg['status'] == 'success') {
        var request2 = $.ajax({
          url: "/account/settings/get_all_tokens",
          method: "GET",
        });
        request2.done(function(ajax) {
          $('#ajax').html(ajax);
          console.log(ajax);
        });
        request2.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
          alert("Request failed: " + textStatus);
        });
      }
    });

    request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
      alert("Request failed: " + textStatus);
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

HTML

```
<div class="api-cta-container">
   <p> <%= t("account.settings.api.disclaimer_text_html") %></p>
   <button type="button" id="api_key" class="btn btn-default"><%= 
   t("account.settings.api.add_api_key") %></button>
   <%#= link_to t("account.settings.api.add_api_key"), 
   /account/settings/api_tokens, method: :post, class: "btn btn-default" %>
</div>

<table class="table" id="ajax">
<thead>
    <tr>
    <th><%= t("global.name") %> <</th>
    <th><%= t("global.creation_date") %></th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<% @all_tokens.each_with_index do |token, index|%>
<tr>
    <td><%= (index+1) %></td>
    <td><%= token.created_at %></td>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><%= t("global.edit") %> <i class="fa fa-sort-desc" aria-hidden="true"><i></button>
    </td>
</tr>
<% end %>
</tbody>
```

Data in Console: After success function, this is the data in Object

```
(4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0:{granted_by: "service", created_at: "2018-07-23T01:06:12.716-04:00", 
time_to_live: 1532927173, refresh_token_expires_at: "2018-07- 
30T01:06:12.714-04:00", client_id: "0f28ad93-d481-47f5-aaec- 
5b9d9b1edff9", …}
1:{granted_by: "service", created_at: "2018-07-23T00:37:29.244-04:00", 
time_to_live: 1532925449, refresh_token_expires_at: "2018-07- 
30T00:37:29.243-04:00", client_id: "0f28ad93-d481-47f5-aaec- 
5b9d9b1edff9", …}
2:{}
3:{}  .........
```

[After Clicking API Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ywju.jpg)  [After Refreshing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YZawK.png)

Comment: show your sample data from the ajax request

Comment: (12) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0
:
{granted_by: "service", created_at: "2018-07-23T01:06:12.716-04:00", time_to_live: 1532927173, refresh_token_expires_at: "2018-07-30T01:06:12.714-04:00", client_id: "0f28ad93-d481-47f5-aaec-5b9d9b1edff9", …}
1
:
{granted_by: "service", created_at: "2018-07-23T00:37:29.244-04:00", time_to_live: 1532925449, refresh_token_expires_at: "2018-07-30T00:37:29.243-04:00", client_id: "0f28ad93-d481-47f5-aaec-5b9d9b1edff9", …}

Comment: can you edit your question with the sample data in a readable format, its very hard to read from the comments

Comment: Edited! Check if it works for you?

Comment: @Akzea where is #api_key in html ?

Comment: I still can't read what the response data is without you expanding it but it looks like you are trying to replace the content of whole table from the ajax request, does you data have the required structure for a table with all the `<tr>` and `<td>` ?

Comment: its a button id! check it now.

Comment: See the Image @Subash. When I'm click on Request New API button. Giving me no View of Table. After Refreshing showing me last generated key

Comment: @Akzea I request to provide plunkr for this. It's working for me in with native HTML.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $.ajax({
    url: "/account/settings/api_token",
    method: "POST",
  }).done(function(msg) {
    if (msg['status'] == 'success') {
      $.ajax({
        url: "/account/settings/get_all_tokens",
        method: "GET",
      }).done(function(ajax) {
        $('#ajax').html(ajax);
        console.log(ajax);
      }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
        console.log("Request2 failed: " + textStatus);
      });
    }
  }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
    console.log("Request1 failed: " + textStatus);
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Try this. If this helps. Or use jQuery.When

Comment: still not updating on Button Click. Above code is doing same, updating after refreshing the page.